# Flake8 - how to exclude all files from a project by listing every file?

Tags: python, lint, flake8

I am setting up `flake8` on a legacy Python code base. My idea was to explicitly list the names of all the `.py` files present in a form similar to this:

```
[flake8]
files_to_ignore = 
  foo.py,
  bar.py,
  spam.py
```

Then, when running `flake8` on the project, it will pass because there are no files to be run on. Then we fix a single file and exclude it from the list which means it will be checked by the linter. Then process repeats for each existing file.

However, I cannot see any way to exclude all files by listing them explicitly from reading the docs. There is `--exclude=<patterns>` but this will ignore all files (I won't be able to filter files by names).

I have found that it is possible to ignore the whole file by adding a line `# flake8: noqa` on an empty line. Is it my only choice to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> There is `--exclude=<patterns>` but this will ignore all files (I won't be able to filter files by names).

A single filename *is a pattern*, a pattern that matches just a single filename. The default value for `exclude` is `.svn,CVS,.bzr,.hg,.git,__pycache__,.tox`, which is a sequence of literal file and directory names.

Just list your filenames as the excluded patterns, as you remove individual names from the list they'll be checked.

`flake8` first tests the base filename (no path), then the absolute path against each pattern. If your filenames are not unique (appear in multiple locations in your file tree), then prefix the files with the relative project path prefixed with `*/`; so in the following tree

```
project/
├── bar
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── example.py
├── example.py
└── foo
    ├── __init__.py
    └── example.py
```

the patterns `*/project/example.py`, `*/project/foo/example.py` and `*/project/bar/example.py` match the 3 individual `example.py` files exactly.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that. I've specified the path to the file (folder with the filename), however since it is a pattern, files with the same name stored in different subfolders will make this strategy unusable - they are ignored altogether.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov: only if the pattern matches on a filename. Include a directory and slash would help here.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately ignores both files if they have the same name yet located in different directories. I've used the directory/filename structure and it did not work. Are you able to make it working for a simple two folders with a file of the same name stored with the same name?

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov: I added an example.

Comment: @Marijn, thanks for the example. I have to use `[flake8]
exclude = project/example.py, project/foo/example.py, project/bar/example.py` to be able to filter out them individually. So, `*/project/foo/example.py` doesn't work, but `project/foo/example.py` - looks like on Windows machine the path without the stars is needed. Thanks for the help!